# Android - How to use XML feed from webpage?

Tags: android, json, xml

Today i have a new challenge which is to integrate XML feed from a webpage into my app.

The thing is, im not really sure if this is XML or not:

```
get leagues from file
league ID: 1
load scores file
updating live fixtures
string(14) "No live scores"
object(SimpleXMLElement)#20 (1) {
["AccountInformation"] => string(136) "Data requested at 3/8/2017 9:32:47 AM from XXX.XX.XX.XX, Username: XXXXXX. Your current supscription runs out on 2/28/2018 5:02:25 PM."
}
no live matches
league ID: 4
load scores file
updating live fixtures
string(14) "No live scores"
object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
  ["AccountInformation"] => string(136) "Data requested at 3/8/2017 9:32:47 AM from XXX.XX.XX.XX, Username: XXXXXX. Your current supscription runs out on 2/28/2018 5:02:25 PM."
}
no live matches
league ID: 10
load scores file
updating live fixtures
string(14) "No live scores"
object(SimpleXMLElement)#18 (1) {
  ["AccountInformation"] => string(136) "Data requested at 3/8/2017 9:32:47 AM from XXX.XX.XX.XX, Username: XXXXXX. Your current supscription runs out on 2/28/2018 5:02:25 PM."
}
no live matches
```

How can i use this feed to show the livescores of a football match?
i have really no clue where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jsoup Library It may Help you to get data from webpage.
https://jsoup.org/download

Here is the tutorial how it is used in Android
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Hope it will help you.